# quasi-components of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: general-topology

i'm searching For the quasi components of $\mathbb{Q}$ with the topology induced by $\mathbb{R}$.

I suspect that there is only one quasi component, because of the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ has only one Clopen.

Comment: No, in fact $\Bbb Q$ has a lot of quasicomponents. Hint: If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are irrational then $(\alpha,\beta)\cap\Bbb Q$ is a clopen subset of $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Q}$ has lots of clopen sets, among which all sets of the form $(a,b) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ where $a,b$ are both irrational.

These clopen sets can be used to show that all quasi-components are singletons.